# Customising emacs to use biblatex-biber instead of bibtex

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, emacs, biber

I use biblatex, but I still go through running bibtex on my .bib files, rather than [biblatex-biber](http://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/), which is/will be preferred. How do I arrange for `C-c C-c` to run the relevant biber command, rather than bibtex?

Comment: You can also use latexmk (which automatically runs biber when it's needed for a document) with emacs, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587287/how-do-i-bind-latexmk-to-one-key-in-emacs-and-have-it-show-errors-if-there-are-a

Comment: You may also want to setup Emacs for editing [biblatex  bibliography files](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78456/5701).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First, set AucTeX to use Biber:

```
M-x customize-variable RET TeX-command-BibTeX RET
```

and enter `Biber` in the text field.

Then, add the appropriate command:

```
M-x customize-variable RET TeX-command-list RET
```

with the following options:

- Name: `Biber`
- Command: `biber %s.bcf`
- How: `TeX-run-BibTeX`

A more elaborate setup could be made to automatically check the backend and set `TeX-command-BibTeX` accordingly.

Answer (score 17):

I've just updated the dev biber doc with instructions for this (and for TeXworks)

http://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/development/documentation/biber.pdf

I have patched files for AUCTeX 11.86 which implement much more robust biber/biblatex support, details in the biber doc. New features are - much more biblatex macro font-lock highlighting, auto-detection of biber/bibtex usage, much better auto-prompting for which tool to run next etc. If you use these updated lisp files, no extra setup is needed at all.

UPDATE: AucTeX 11.87 is now released and includes this biber support.

Comment: Great work! Relatedly there is [biblatex support in BibTeX mode since Emacs 24.1](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78456/5701).