# What BibTeX editors / bibliography managers have an up to date support for biblatex?

Tags: biblatex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bibliography tools that are compatible with biblatex and biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23942/bibliography-tools-that-are-compatible-with-biblatex-and-biber)

I am looking for an easy to use bibliography manager in the style of jabref or pybliographer, that would support the current biblatex extensions to the `.bib` format, such as `@online` entries, `location` fields etc., that I could recommend to someone who is just learning how to use bibtex/biblatex.

Comment: JabRef does support biblatex, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23976/1376.

Comment: Indeed.  For some reason, that question never came up when I was searching, nor was it suggested as a similar question.