# Convert bib file from BibTeX to biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I have a `bib` file that I have been using with BibTeX for a number of years. I have now switched to creating my bibliographies with `biber` and the `biblatex` package. Every once in a while I need to manipulate a field or add a field into the `bib` file to get the most out of `biblatex`. This works fine from a technical stand point. From a user interface vantage, this is an utter failure with JabRef which I use to manage my `bib` file on Linux. If I add a `biblatex` specific field JabRef doesn't display it nicely. If I switch JabRef to `biblatex` mode it doesn't handle my old `bib` entries well. For example, I run into major problems with the BibTeX `year` field and the `biblatex` `date` field as well as the `journal` versus `journatitle` fields.

Is there a GUI that runs on Linux for managing a `bib` file that has both BibTeX and `biblatex` fields? I think that at this point I would be comfortable converting my `bib` file from BibTeX to `biblatex`. Is there a converter that does this? I am a little worried that this will make importing citations from the web difficult since most publishers still use the BibTeX fields.

Comment: I tend to find JabRef rather irritating and inflexible, and now use the same text editors (notepad++ on windows, jEdit on Linux) for my .bib files as for my .tex.  They're content-agnostic, which is nice when pasting multiple entries in one go, from a scratch file or email that may have extraneous text, and both allow regexp-based find/replace, which you could easily use to add a `journaltitle` field below every `journal` field.

Comment: It partly depends what you really want. For example, `biblatex` will treat `journal` as an alias for `journaltitle`, so you could just leave this alone (and avoid duplication). On the other hand, if you are happy to switch to `biblatex`-only working then a text editor is probably the best way to rename the fields.

Comment: In JabRef you can rename fields with Search --> Set/clear/rename fields. That will allow you to quickly convert e.g. all `journal` to `journaltitle`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT that is a useful function.

Comment: @JosephWright `biblatex` treats it as an alias, but JabRef does not. I was hoping that someone with better regex foo than me had a converter. While I could probably figure out how to change `journal` to `journaltitle` changing `month` to a numeric value and then combining with `year` to form `date` is beyond me.

Comment: IIRC, you don't need to combine year and month into date.  (I never used the month field, however.)

Comment: [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23976) states that JabRef has a `biblatex` mode.

Comment: @henrique yes JabRef has a `biblatex` mode (I mention it in my question). The problem is `biblatex` mode doesn't work with `bibtex` type `bib` files.

Comment: @DanielE.Shub, sorry, tldr, please ignore my stupid comment. `:$`

Comment: @StrongBad I think you used only some biblatex fields. It's possible add to `Require` or `Optional` fields in `options/customize entry types` and write the `biblatex` field and click in add button (Not select from the list).

Comment: @StrongBad (Sorry I pressed enter key in the above comment) Other options is add a 'new tab' using `option/set up general fields`. For example:

`Biblatex:jurnaltitle;booktitle;addendum;maintitle;booksubtitle;eventtitle;venue`

Add a new tab with the name `biblatex` and these fields. 

It helps?

Answer (score 5):

My personal preference is for versatile tools, rather than using JabRef (which I find rather irritating and inflexible -- the bibtex vs. biblatex modes issue in the question). I therefore use a decent text editor to maintain my .bib files (namely jEdit, though on Windows I liked notepad++). Any text editor will give you a content-agnostic paste without trying to be clever.  For example you may want to manually merge scratch files, or import from a source (such as an email) with extraneous text that you'll need to edit out.

Both the editors above allow regexp based find/replace.  This could easily allow adding a `journaltitle` field after every `journal` field, for example, or comment out fields based on their value or lack of one.

This approach has served me well as I took the same master .bib file from being only used with bibtex to mainly used with biblatex (I still have to use bibtex as part of the journal submission process).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question, "Is there a converter that does this?",  rbibutils ( https://github.com/GeoBosh/rbibutils ) should provide the ability to convert from bibtex to biblatex.

```
> library(rbibutils)
> bibConvert("in-bibtex.bib", "out-biblatex.bib", informat = "bibtex", outformat = "biblatex")
```