# Jabref, ref of company website

Tags: bibtex, apa-style

I am using Jabref to manage biblografy. I want to get

Z+F Imager, 2013: Retrieved 18 / 09 / 2013, from http://www.zf-laser.com:

Here is a minimal example.
% my Question

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}% Use this line for the print version of the thesis

\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname1.bib}
@MISC{Imager2013,
  url = {http://www.zf-laser.com},
  year = {2013},
  author = {Z+F Imager},
  title = {Z+F Imager web-site},
  howpublished = {2013},
  month = {09},
  owner = {sS},
  timestamp = {2013.09.16}

}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

%%%%%%%%%%%%% begin Bibliography %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\citet{Imager2013}\\

\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\bibliography{\jobname1}

\end{document}
```

% output%

```
Imager, Z. (2013). Z+f imager web-site. 2013.
```

How can I manage my fields to get required output.

Comment: The `apalike` style doesn't know what to do with the `url` field, nor with `timestamp`. You could add it as a `note`: `note={Retrieved on 18/09/2013 from \url{http://www.zf-laser.com}}` Load the `url` package or leave out `\url`.

Comment: I would also look into using `biblatex`.  Are you particularly attached to BibTeX/`natbib`?  (That is, would you accept a BibLaTeX solution?)

Comment: I m using natbib and I am happy with it for my  work. Can some one provide solution using my file.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to stick with `natbib`, the best you can do is probably this.

Note that I kept the `title` field, as it is a good idea to have a little more than the author to go by.

You can use the `howpublished` or `note` field to provide the information about URL and access date (though, semantically, `howpublished` is probably only apt for the URL, not the retrieval date).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Imager2013,
  url = {http://www.zf-laser.com},
  year = {2013},
  author = {{Z+F Imager}},
  title = {{Z+F} {Imager} web-site},
  month = {09},
  note = {Retrieved on 18/09/2013 from \url{http://www.zf-laser.com}},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citet{Imager2013}

\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

which gives
[image]

If you do want to use the `url` field, you will have to modify the `apalike` style quite a bit, as it is as of now unaware of any `url`-related features.

---

If you don't mind using [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), the following code snippet is the way to go.
`biblatex` offers a `natbib` compatibility mode (see [§ 3.7.9 of the documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)) and JabRef supports `biblatex` (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23976/35864)).

```
\documentclass[american]{article}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,natbib,urldate=short]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{Imager2013,
  url = {http://www.zf-laser.com},
  year = {2013},
  author = {{Z+F Imager}},
  title = {{Z+F} {Imager} web-site},
  month = {09},
  url = {http://www.zf-laser.com},
  urldate = {2013-09-18},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citet{Imager2013}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]