# Use all biblatex fields in bibdesk

Tags: biblatex, bibdesk

In the BibDesk wiki (BibDesk Tips and Tricks) there is some information on customizing BibDesk for biblatex, including a link to a TypeInfo file that can be used to create all of the biblatex fields automatically. 
The has to be saved as ~/Library/Application Support/BibDesk/TypeInfo.plist.

Im using texmaker, bibDesk under osx 10.9.5. The folder doesn't exist so I created it. Didn't help.

Does anybody know where to copy the "TypeInfo.plist" file?

Alan Munn refers to this in that Question: [Bibliography tools that are compatible with biblatex and biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23942/bibliography-tools-that-are-compatible-with-biblatex-and-biber/25758#25758)

Comment: That is the correct location. You can also edit the types via BibDesk's preferences (the Defaults pane), which creates and/or modifies that file as needed. What did you expect to happen, and how did it differ from what you saw?

Comment: I expected when I create a new publication and klick on the type (next to the cite key) that I have different/more options to choose from. What happened is nothing. No change to that field

Comment: /Library/Application Support/BibDesk/TypeInfo.plist - is what I get when I click on "get info" in finder...

Comment: This needs to go in the Library folder under your home directory, not the `/Library` folder. On 10.9, you may need to hold down Option and use the Go menu in Finder to open this folder.

Comment: perfekt! That did the trick. It was more a "how to use a mac" problem but still, thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad that helped. I added a note to @AlanMunn's answer to try and clarify it. Apple did us no favors by hiding `~/Library` in 10.7, unfortunately.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell Want to make that an answer, so this question can be marked as resolved?

Comment: it resolved my problem.