# How to create a .bib file and use it in .tex file?

Tags: bibliographies

I've got something like this:
[image]

Here just before section 4, I was asked to make a `.bib` file  that contains three bibliographic references. So far the examples  I've seen, it contains only one reference to data. To implement three references, should I write like this:

```
@book{Books, 
title="Microprocessor and Interfacing.", 
author="Douglas V. Hall.",

title="The Elements of Style. ", 
author="W. Strunk and E.B. White.",

title="The Theory of Everything ", 
author="Stephen Hawking",
}
```

And how do I call it from `.tex` file, like this:

```
\bibliogrphy{online2}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

where online2 is the folder where both the `.bib` and `.tex` files are.

And how to show only two contents like it's said in the image(just before section 4)? Is there anything like indexing system?

And another thing is, how to implement the side by side view? Like section 1 is on the left side and section 4 is on the right?

Comment: Is this a homework question? There are lots of basic guides to LaTeX that can help answer this.

Comment: See e.g. [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/2693).

Comment: I have already gone through the LaTeX wikibook but didn't understand the contents properly. Moreover, my problem is kinda different that includes some additional things like showing some particular things from .bib file. And also, I've never worked with .bib file. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: The LaTeX wikibook is not very good. Here's a nice basic introduction to using `bibtex`. [Using bibtex: a short guide](https://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/latex/BIBTEX.HTM).

Comment: Also I highly recommend using a bibliography management tool.  See [Bibliography tools that are compatible with biblatex and biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23942/2693). (This question talks about the `biblatex` compatibility, but the answers are applicable more generally.)  Jabref (cross-platform) and BibDesk (Mac) are the two most widely used.

Comment: Have you asked your instructor for help? The instructions say that these exercises are using material covered in your last two lectures. It is best to start from the framework you've been given and to ask your instructor for clarification if necessary.

Comment: The `@book{key, ...}` code in the database reference is only for  one entry, so with one field and only one author field (and usually some others fields). The "key"  part is the identifier of that reference, so you should write  `@book{keya, ...} @book{keyb, ...} @book{keyc, ...}` for tree books. 
Pay attention to Alan comment. JabRef will help you to understand this syntax.