# What would be a good reference manager for bibtex?

Tags: bibtex, jabref

I was previously using JabRef in Windows as the bibtex reference manager for my research related work. But I decided to change my laptop and bought a MacBook. So the issue is JabRef is not working in MacOS Catalina 10.15.4. Can anyone please suggest me a good reference manager for bibtex which is compatible with MacOS Catalina ?

Thanks.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25758/38616

Comment: I tried BibDesk as well, but it does not seem to be compatible with MacOS Catalina.

Comment: Jabref 5.0 is working fine under Mac OS Catalina. Could you please report any issues to https://github.com/JabRef/jabref

Comment: I installed Jabref 5.0 and now it seems working well. But the previous time I installed it, the application was not laggy at all.

Comment: @GayanLankeshwara You can try the latest development version (https://builds.jabref.org/master), we massively improved the performance compared to the 5.0 version.

Comment: @ChristophS Right now I am using the recommended stable version. Anyhow I will try to download the latest version,.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ChristophS Hey Chris, although it seems that JabRef is working on Catalina, it does not go directly go to the Applications folder, instead need to follow a tedious process to open JabRef once needed. Could you please help me with this ? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please ask in our forum?  (I don't have a Mac) https://discourse.jabref.org/