# Setting up RefTeX with biblatex citation commands

Tags: biblatex, emacs, csquotes, reftex

How do I setup RefTeX with biblatex's citation commands? In [Workflow for managing references?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18848/workflow-for-managing-references/18855#18855) Seamus describes a workflow with RefTeX and mentions that

> it wouldn't be too tricky to add `\autocite` and friends to aucTeX's
>   cite insertion mechanism.

The biblatex citation commands I'd like to use with RefTeX is `\autocite`, `\smartcite` and `\textcite`. Also, I'd like RefTeX to work with csquotes' `\blockcquote`.

Note that I am not asking for anything that has to do with compilation (like  [Customising emacs to use biblatex-biber instead of bibtex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3904/customising-emacs-to-use-biblatex-biber-instead-of-bibtex)).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The variable you need to hook into is `reftex-cite-format`.  Somewhere in my Emacs init file, I have this code:

```lisp
(eval-after-load 'reftex-vars
  '(progn
     ;; (also some other reftex-related customizations)
     (setq reftex-cite-format
           '((?\C-m . "\\cite[]{%l}")
             (?f . "\\footcite[][]{%l}")
             (?t . "\\textcite[]{%l}")
             (?p . "\\parencite[]{%l}")
             (?o . "\\citepr[]{%l}")
             (?n . "\\nocite{%l}")))))
```

You should to add your desired commands to this list.  The first element in each pair is the letter you want to press after `C-c [` to select the given citation format.  The empty square brackets denote optional arguments; RefTeX has variables to control whether it prompts your for those.  And `%l` is where the cite key goes.

(You could also set this variable via `M-x customize-variable`, but I loathe that particular feature of Emacs.)

I'm not sure what the syntax of `\blockcquote` is...if it has more non-optional arguments than just a cite key, RefTeX might not be able to fully support it (i.e., it inserts the command but you then have to move backwards to fill out other arguments).

Comment: What's the line `;; ...` for?

Comment: @N.N., just to indicate that other reftex-related customizations go there.  I've edited to clarify.

Comment: Why is `eval-after-load` used here? http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html says "Normally, well-designed Lisp programs should not use `eval-after-load`."

Comment: @N.N., your link also says "But it is OK to use `eval-after-load` in your personal customizations if you don't feel that they must meet the design standards [...] for wider use." Since this code is run at emacs startup, I use `eval-after-load` to defer loading the `reftex-vars` library (until the first TeX file is opened), which cuts down on startup time – drastically, if you use `eval-after-load` consistently. It's a fairly common `.emacs` idiom AFAIK. It's also possible to use the `M-x customize` interface for deferred variable setting, but I dislike it (and it can't really be copy/pasted).

Comment: It was quite easy to use the loathed `customize-variable` also. `M-x customize-set-value`, enter `customize-set-value`, enter `reftex-cite-format`, enter `format string`, enter `\autocite[]{%l}`. (Should I add this as another answer?)

Answer (score 10):

Another way to integrate `biblatex` and `csquotes` with RefTeX is via *[YASnippet](http://capitaomorte.github.com/yasnippet/)*.

You make a snippet for every citation macro you want to use and have the snippets call `reftex-citation`.

I use a setup where I type "ct" and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and then I get to choose between the two following snippets.

For `\auctocite`:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: autocite \autocite
# key: ct
# --
\autocite[$3]{${2:label$(unless yas/modified-p (reftex-citation 'dont-insert))}}$0
```

For `\textcite`:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: textcite \textcite
# key: ct
# --
\textcite[$3]{${2:label$(unless yas/modified-p (reftex-citation 'dont-insert))}}$0
```

[image: biblatex citations called via YASnippet]

I also use the following for `\blockcquote`:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: Formal blockquote \blockcquote
# key: fbq
# expand-env: ((yas/indent-line 'fixed))
# --
\blockcquote[$2]{${1:label$(unless yas/modified-p (reftex-citation 'dont-insert))}}{%
$0%
}
```

For a collection of snippets for citing with biblatex see https://github.com/Sleft/yasnippet-latex-mode/tree/master/cite.

Answer (score 4):

To get RefTeX to work with `csquotes` package I use this in my `.emacs`:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex"
 '(TeX-add-style-hook "csquotes"
   (lambda ()
    (TeX-add-symbols
     '("textcquote" [ "pre-note (post-note if alone)" ] [ "post-note" ] TeX-arg-cite  [ "Punctuation" ] t ignore ignore)
     '("blockcquote" [ "pre-note (post-note if alone)" ] [ "post-note" ] TeX-arg-cite  [ "Punctuation" ] t ignore ignore)
     '("foreigntextcquote"  "Language"  [ "pre-note (post-note if alone)" ] [ "post-note" ] TeX-arg-cite  [ "Punctuation" ] t ignore ignore)
     '("foreignblockcquote" "Language" [ "pre-note (post-note if alone)" ] [ "post-note" ] TeX-arg-cite  [ "Punctuation" ] t ignore ignore)
     ))))
```

This way when you run `C-c C-m blockcquote` it will prompt you for the correct arguments and you will get the RefTeX-dialog for choosing a citation label.

I have taken this from somewhere but don't remember where. The important part if you need to edit it is invoking `TeX-arg-cite` for the correct argument (citation label) of the macros.

Comment: I tried this but it says `C-c m` is undefined.