# reftex-cite-format customizations not loading

Tags: biblatex, emacs, auctex, reftex

RefTeX will no longer load my custom citations commands when using the lines from [Setting up RefTeX with biblatex citation commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31966/) in my init file. Nothing changed in my init file, but it no longer loads the custom citations commands and only shows the default citation commands with `C-c [`.

Is there any reason for this? I am using Ubuntu, and the same init file loads correctly in Windows.

Comment: Well, presumably *something* has changed since it last worked, but I'm not sure how we're supposed to guess at this point. Are you implying that the only thing in your `.emacs` are those lines you've linked to? Are you suggesting that you error messages are given when you open Emacs? Are you saying that your init files are identical on your two OSes?

Comment: Did you do an update on one of your systems? Did really nothing (however minute) change?

Comment: After trying to test this with other .tex files, I figured out that this is occurring for my document that is using `\documentclass[man,12pt]{apa6}`. The same document works properly on Windows. If I comment this line out and save the document, the document.el file in the 'auto' folder updates. When I reopen the document the custom commands return. So it appears to be some issue with how emacs and `apa6` interact.

Comment: If I remove the lines `"apa6"` and `"apa612"` from `(TeX-run-style-hooks)` the problem goes away. Any time I save the document, these lines will reappear, recreating the problem.

Comment: I was able to fix the problem by disabling the line `(setq TeX-auto-save t)` in my `init` file, and deleting the `auto` directory created by AUCTeX. There appears to be an interaction with this command and the `apa6` class. Only in Ubuntu, not in Windows.

Comment: If you have found a solution it would be nice of you could post it so other people that have the same problem are able to find it. Plus you can accept your answer to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some interaction between the `apa6` style and the AUCTeX automatic file parsing when using emacs in Ubuntu that did not allow my custom citation commands to work.

I disabled `(setq TeX-auto-save t)` in my `init.el` and deleted the `auto` subdirectory in my working folder. Info about the disabled option can be found here: [Automatic Parsing of TeX Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Parsing-Files.html).