# Does Emacs support editing bibliography files for biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, emacs

Emacs includes `bibtex-mode` for editing bibliography files used by BibTeX. Is there a way to make it support the bibliography files used by `biblatex`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Since Emacs 24.1](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/NEWS.24.1) `bibtex-mode` supports `biblatex`:

> *** BibTeX mode now supports biblatex. Use the variable `bibtex-dialect' to select different BibTeX dialects.

To use it you can for example set it as a [file variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables) to bibliography files by adding the following to their first line:

```
-*- mode:bibtex; bibtex-dialect: biblatex -*-
```

Comment: On a side note [AUCTeX support for biblatex and biber is enhanced with version 11.87](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4844/5701).

Comment: How did I miss this until now?!!  This is great.

Comment: It seems that the above does not work and that you have to say `-*- mode:bibtex; eval: (bibtex-set-dialect 'biblatex); -*-` instead

Comment: You could also add `(setq bibtex-set-dialect 'biblatex)` to your `init.le` file.